# Mixing variables into an array when inserting values

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

I have a function that inserts a load of values into a database. Not a problem but I have a condition that changes the mysql statement. The problem is is the way wordpress constructs the statement, below is what I've tried...

```
public function sqlInsertTicket($event, $customer, $ticket){

    $reference = 0;

    if ($customer['gender']=="F"){
        $table = "f_ti";
        $sql ='"ft_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","booking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'"';
    }
    if ($customer['gender']=="M"){
        $table = "m_ti";
        $sql ='"ticket_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","mbooking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'"';
    }
    $this->edb->insert(
                $table,
                array(
                        $sql,
                        'event_id'                  =>  $event['id'],
                        'original_ev'               =>  $event['id'],
                        'age'                       =>  $customer['age']
                    )
            );
    return $this->edb->insert_id;
}
```

I've removed a lot of the values but you can see what I'm trying to do. The $sql variable is what changes. I could write the whole thing out twice but, I've got lots of these to do and it would save a lot of time in the long run.

Wordpress is basically treating the $sql as 0 for the column name and doing crazy things with the values.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `string` ....

```
$sql ='"ft_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","booking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'"';
```

... but expecting it to operate as an array...

```
array(
    $sql,
    'event_id' =>  $event['id'],
```

This has nothing to do with how WordPress does anything. This is pure PHP. You have literally created this:

```
array(
    [] => "ft_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","booking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'",
    'event_id' =>  $event['id'],
```

You need to build the array dynamically.

```
 $dynargs = array(
     'event_id'                  =>  $event['id'],
     'original_ev'               =>  $event['id'],
     'age'                       =>  $customer['age']
 )

if ($customer['gender']=="F"){
    $table = "f_ti";
    $dynargs['ft_num'] = $ticket['number'];
    $dynargs['booking_id'] = $ticket['booking'];
} elseif ($customer['gender']=="M"){
    $table = "m_ti";
    $dynargs['ticket_num'] = $ticket['number'];
    $dynargs['mbooking_id'] = $ticket['booking'];
}
$this->edb->insert(
            $table,
            $dynargs
        );
return $this->edb->insert_id;
```

I wrote that on the spot. It may be buggy but that is the idea.

Comment: I read through my question and had the same brainwave! But your getting the kudos! I've been awake for far too long, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should start with the fact that the two situations are exclusive, so either the gender is `M` or `F`.

```
if ($customer['gender']=="F"){
    $table = "f_ti";
    $sql ='"ft_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","booking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'"';
} else if ($customer['gender']=="M"){
    $table = "m_ti";
    $sql ='"ticket_num"=>"'.$ticket['number'].'","mbooking_id"=>"'.$ticket['booking'].'"';
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, that is already the case?